# redis master slave replication stopped working

Tags: redis, replication, database-replication, master-slave

I'm trying to figure out how to troubleshoot my redis master / slave replication.  It has "just stopped" working.

**Setup Information**

Let's say my master's IP address is 10.1.2.3

**Here's what I've checked so far:**

1. I've restarted redis on both the master and slave... but anytime I run INFO REPLICATION on the slave it shows the link as "down"
2. Ran netstat -lnp on both the master and slave.  Here's the output from the master:

> ```
> masterdb:~# netstat -lnp | grep 6379
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21611/redis-server
> tcp        0      0 10.1.2.3:6379      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21611/redis-server
> ```

And from the slave machine:

> ```
> slavedb:~# netstat -lnp | grep 6379
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5577/redis-server
> tcp        0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      5577/redis-server
> slavedb:~#
> ```

3. I've checked the logs on both the master and the slave and I don't see any error messages. But I see timeout messages on the slave... which I think I've seen before, even when replication was working.  The log looks like this on the slave:

> ```
> 5577:S 26 Oct 13:17:19.510 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
> 5577:S 26 Oct 13:18:20.597 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
> 5577:S 26 Oct 13:18:20.597 * Connecting to MASTER 10.1.2.3:6379
> 5577:S 26 Oct 13:18:20.597 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
> 5577:S 26 Oct 13:19:21.685 # Timeout connecting to the MASTER...
> ```

4. When i start the redis-cli on the slave and re-issue the slaveof command, i get this message:

   127.0.0.1:6379> slaveof 10.1.2.3 6379
   OK Already connected to specified master
   127.0.0.1:6379>
5. I also tried the following commands on the master :

> ```
> 127.0.0.1:6379> save
> OK
> 127.0.0.1:6379> bgsave
> Background saving started
> 127.0.0.1:6379>
> ```

But that didn't resolve anything on the slave.  It still says the link is down when I check the INFO on REPLCIATION:

```
   127.0.0.1:6379> info replication
    # Replication
    role:slave
    master_host:10.1.2.3
    master_port:6379
    master_link_status:down
    master_last_io_seconds_ago:-1
    master_sync_in_progress:0
    slave_repl_offset:1
    master_link_down_since_seconds:1477488462
    slave_priority:100
    slave_read_only:1
    connected_slaves:0
    master_repl_offset:0
    repl_backlog_active:0
    repl_backlog_size:1048576
    repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
    repl_backlog_histlen:0
    127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: I rebooted the slave and it "just came back".  i don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

sounds like a networking issue. Try to 
`telnet masterip 6379` from the slave next time it happens to ensure it is a network issue.

Comment: I did face exact problem, and could confirm `telnet masterip 6379` works fine. so anything else we could check to narrow down root of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is outdated, but nevertheless)
this may be because redis is bound to 127.0.0.1
and the path to the master host address is not correctly routed.

There are two ways to deal with this - either deal with routing, or remove the bind option in the redis config.